My Django-cms 4.1.4 installation does not match django-cms 4.1.4 documentation. How do I add my own template and get it to work with django-cms?
I am having a heck of a time making sense of a fresh install of django-cms 4.1.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.12
I have been looking at some YouTube videos and other pages about django-cms templates. They talk about base.html, full-width templates, but I don't have those in my djang-cms installation. All that is in my base.html is 2 lines:
{# Replace this with your base template #}
{% extends "bootstrap5/base.html" %}. 

The bootstrap5/base.html only contains the django-cms nav-block.
{% extends "djangocms_frontend.html" %}{% load cms_tags menu_tags %}
{% block base_css %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% endblock %}
{% block base_js %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar {% block navbar_options %}navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark{% endblock %}">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{% block brand %}{% endblock %}</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">{% block menubar %}{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 'bootstrap5/menu.html' %}{% endblock %}</ul>
                {% block searchbar %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}

When I look at the django-cms 4.1.4 documentation for Templates, it does not match my installation of django-cms 4.1.4 (I checked the version to be sure):

You’ll find the site’s templates in
django-cms-quickstart/backend/templates


I do not have a django-cms-quickstart folder on my system


By default, pages in your site will use the fullwidth.html template,
the first one listed in the project’s settings.py CMS_TEMPLATES tuple


Nope, no fullwidth.html in settings property CMS_TEMPLATES, just ("base.html", _("Standard"))

I am totally lost, as I can't even use the django-cms documentation to figure this out. I have installed django-cms several times and my setup does not match the documentation for version 4.1.4.
I then tried adding my own template in CMS_TEMPLATES as ('onepage3.html', _("Standard")), but when I try to make a new page, I cannot find a place to select that template. New pages just come up with the django-cms base.html template. I can create pages using that template, but no other. What am I doing wrong?

Well, it turns out, based on feeedback from a django-cms Fellow on Discord, when one installs django-cms manually it does not have all the bits one gets when it is installed using Docker. There is nothing in the official online documentation for django-cms to let you know that a manual installation is not really usable, nor does the documentation say what parts are missing and how to install them to get a fully functional installation. In fact, the documentation says there are three ways to install django-cms - on Divio where you pay for hosting, using Docker, and manually. The reader is lead to believe the manual installation is no different than the Docker installation.
The manual installation is no different than a normal django installation. Create a virtual environment and then run various django-cms commands inside that virtual environment to install and setup django-cms.
After spending over a week chasing my tail as to why I can't get a manual installation working with my own template, I am moving on to a better solution for my clients since I still do not know what bits are missing nor how to install them. However, the django-cms Fellow did offer me the opportunity to edit the django-cms documentation.
